# Fixing a bug in a For loop

Tags: for-loop

This is a question I was asked today at a job interview:

Look at the following code:

```
int n=20;
for (int i =0; i<n; i--)
    print("*");
```

You are allowed to change **one and only one character** in order for the loop to run exactly 20 times.

I wasn't able to answer the question at all.
At first I thought to set i to 40, but then realized that 40 ins't smaller than 20.

My interviewer said that are 5 different answers for this question...

Please help me find the answers.

Comment: Note that this code will run forever. The change is in the post-iteration part of the for-statement.

Comment: This is not javascript nor c#

Comment: Also this is an insanely dumb interview question - what does answering this tell your interviewer about you? You don't want to work at a company with such an interview process

Comment: @ M.kazem Akhgary - thats 2 characters.
@Tal Angel - do you want us to tell you the answer?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, Yes it is. It would run in JS and C#
Forever, but it would work

Comment: @OddmarDam `print` is not a c# command (unless you made a function named that). It is not a javascript command either. Also `int` is not javascript which has neither integers nor type annotations.

Comment: It's not point about `print`, `int`, and so on... @Adrian359 provide answer ;) :D

Comment: Of course its not about that, but the *tags* for the question are c# and javascript, **not** pseudo-code @nelek

Comment: It's a valid question, but it is less about coding and more about problem solving. That it's in the form of a code question is irrelevant. It's otherwise just a riddle. Along the lines of asking someone what you put into a toaster. If the answer is not "Bread" then they don't get the job, I guess.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Yeah, I know but... it's logic test ;) user just used wrong tags... newbie ... anyway, interested.

Comment: According to OP, there are still 4 answers pending :-)

Comment: I will say though, the specific language used is kind of important for more esoteric answers...all sorts of neat bit operations are possible here but rules for these vary from language to language

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change to

```
int n=20;
for (int i =0; i<n; n--)
print("*");
```

Answer (score 9):

An other one could be :

```
int n=20;
for (int i =0; -i<n; i--)
    print("*");
```

Comment: it's good, too... but, it's about *changing*, *not adding* char. ;)

Comment: @nelek no he is changing with one empty character ;)

Answer (score 4):

This one does the job as well:

```
int n=20;
for (int i =0; i+n; i--)
    print("*");
```

Assuming the language implicitly casts integers to booleans, i.e. treats non-zero integers as true and zeros as false.